# MacOS - change behavior of wired earphone button clicks

Tags: headphones, ear-phones

On 10.15.x, is there a way of changing the behavior of the remote button on wired earphones, so that when it gets clicked it does a mute/unmute in WebEx or Zoom?

On iOS, mute/unmute in Zoom/WebEx is the behavior of the lightning earpods when the remote button is clicked - I'd love to be able have this behavior on the desktop as well.

It looks like you could code something up in ControllerMate on previous versions of macOS, but alas, no more. Are there any other viable options out there to get configure this behavior?